# Make QObject wait for its listeners before executing function

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qobject

I'm working with structured light, and I have `QCamera` and `QProjector` classes I wrote. When the projector projects a pattern, it must wait for all attached cameras to capture that pattern before it moves on to the next one.

My current model is this:

- `QProjector` projects an image and emits signal `patternProjected(Pattern*)`.
- Connected `QCamera`s receive the signal and connect to the projector's `hold()` signal (see below). The cameras then begin to capture the image asynchronously and emit `frameCaptured(cv::Mat)` when done.

Previously I had a `hold()` slot in `QProjector`. A camera who wanted the projector to wait for it would call

```
connect(projector,SIGNAL(hold()),camera,SLOT(wait()))`
```

where `camera->wait()` is a dummy function. Then, in `projector->disconnectNotify()`, the projector checks to see if `receivers(SIGNAL(hold()))` is zero. If it is, the projector moves on to the next pattern in its queue; if not it waits some more.

This approach is a hot mess, and it doesn't even work--there is no guarantee that the projector won't move on to the next pattern between emitting `patternProjected()` and receiving the connection from the camera.

Anyone have a cleaner approach, ideally one more in line with the `QObject` philosophy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize a member variable in your `QProjector` with `receivers(SIGNAL(hold()))`, and every time the slot is called, you decrement it. When the counter reaches `0`, you reinitialize with `receivers(SIGNAL(hold()))` and projects another pattern.

Of course, in this scenario `hold()` is a terrible (non-semantic) name, you should rename it to `patternRead()` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, that was really a nudge in the right direction.

I now have an `aboutToAdvance()` signal in the projector, which connects to a `projectorAboutToAdvance()` slot. When this slot gets called, the camera emits `allowProjectorToAdvance(bool allow)` with either true or false depending on whether or not to permit the pattern advance. This is collected by a `permissionToAdvance(bool allow)`, which decrements the `waitingFor` counter, and increments the `deniedAdvance` counter if `allow` is false. If `waitingFor` is zero and `deniedAdvance` nonzero, no advancement is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a mediation object like so:

```
//startWork increments some internal counter
connect(camera_1...n, SIGNAL(captureStarted()), mediator, SLOT(startWork()))

//stopWork decrements the counter, when counter reaches 0 emits trigger()
connect(camera_1...n, SIGNAL(captureFinished()), mediator, SLOT(stopWork()))

//startCapture emits captureStarted
connect(projector, SIGNAL(patternProjected()), camera_1...n, SLOT(startCapture())

//projectNext emits patternProjected
connect(mediator, SIGNAL(trigger()), projector, SLOT(projectNext()))
```